# Maximum likelihood 'mle' delivers NaN standard errors

Tags: r

I'm using the mle function from the stats4 package to estimate my model with maximum likelihood. I obtain reasonable parameter estimates, but some of the standard errors are NaN:

```
require(stats4)
df = read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/uDhQj4LW", stringsAsFactors = F, sep="\t")

LL <- function(b0, b1, b2, b3) {

  xmu = b0 + b1 * df$brentcpl
  xsi = b2 + b3 * df$brentcpl
  lls = log(1 / df$price / xsi / sqrt (2*pi)) - (log(df$price) - xmu)^2/ 2 / xsi^2
  lls[is.nan(lls)] = -100 - (b0 + b1 + b2 + b3)^2
  #print(paste0("b0 ", b0, "b1 ", b1, " b2 ", b2, " b3 ", b3, " mu ", min(xmu), " xsi ", min(xsi)))
  #print(sum(lls))
  -sum(lls) 
}

estres = mle(LL, start = list(b0 = 4.5171634,
                              b1 = .00949832,
                              b2 = .03892378,
                              b3 = .00069329     
))

summary(estres)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(b0 = 4.5171634, b1 = 0.00949832, 
    b2 = 0.03892378, b3 = 0.00069329))

Coefficients:
       Estimate   Std. Error
b0  4.495186481 0.0193639611
b1  0.007735690 0.0006672378
b2 -0.012258204 0.0008411522
b3  0.001435819          NaN

-2 log L: 1205.609 
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object@vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

What can go wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Being able to reproduce your problem would be very helpful.

Comment: @JuliusVainora, you're right, sorry ... added the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance-covariance matrix of the model can be obtained using:

```
estres@vcov
#               b0            b1            b2            b3
# b0  3.749630e-04 -1.286236e-05  5.564893e-06 -9.836086e-11
# b1 -1.286236e-05  4.452062e-07 -1.409643e-07  3.231134e-12
# b2  5.564893e-06 -1.409643e-07  7.075369e-07  1.908407e-11
# b3 -9.836086e-11  3.231134e-12  1.908407e-11 -6.241188e-17
```

The variance of `b3` (at position [4,4]) is very small but negative.
In `mle` the variance-covariance matrix was estimated by calculating the inverse of the Hessian:

```
solve(oout$hessian)
```

where `oout$hessian` is

```
#               b0            b1            b2            b3
# b0  2.752547e+05  8.091507e+06 -1.634045e+04  -19890328389
# b1  8.091507e+06  2.398502e+08 -7.378089e+05 -560469634334
# b2 -1.634045e+04 -7.378089e+05  1.871352e+05   44776772461
# b3 -1.989033e+10 -5.604696e+11  4.477677e+10    7443899452
```

You can try to fix the problem changing the scale of `df$brentcpl`:

```
df$brentcpl <- df$brentcpl/100
estres = mle(LL, start = list(b0 = 5,
                              b1 = .25,
                              b2 = .25,
                              b3 = .25     
))
summary(estres)

# Maximum likelihood estimation
# Call:
# mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(b0 = 5, b1 = 0.25, b2 = 0.25, 
#     b3 = 0.25)    
# Coefficients:
#       Estimate  Std. Error
# b0  4.54064769 0.013846337
# b1  0.61318128 0.044016385
# b2  0.06951554 0.008852508
# b3 -0.16738634 0.028168022
# -2 log L: 1078.542
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure whether we can interpret the estimated variance of b3 as being that close to zero, or whether this indicates some kind of error in the estimation that should be dealt with otherwise.

Comment: You are right, seems to be a numerical problem ... multiplying the coefficient by 1000 and dividing by 1000 in the likelihood function solves it ... seems to be the solution. I still think that just replacing with 0's is not that good.

Comment: @bonifaz I edited my answer suggesting (for example) to divide `brentcpl` by 100. I get convergence. But small changes of the initial condition lead to different solutions. The estimation of parameters seem very sensitive.